# How to update div in dom with react

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have this select in a react component

```
<Select defaultValue="" style={{ width: 200 }} onChange={handleChange}>
      <OptGroup label={correctGroup[0].Tag}>
        <Option value={correctGroup[0].Text}>{correctGroup[0].Text}</Option>
        <Option value={correctGroup[1].Text}>{correctGroup[1].Text}</Option>
        <Option value={correctGroup[2].Text}>{correctGroup[2].Text}</Option>
      </OptGroup>
      <OptGroup label={wordForSelect[0].Tag}>
        <Option value={wordForSelect[0].Text}>{wordForSelect[0].Text}</Option>
        <Option value={wordForSelect[1].Text}>{wordForSelect[1].Text}</Option>
        <Option value={wordForSelect[2].Text}>{wordForSelect[2].Text}</Option>
      </OptGroup>
    </Select>
```

Once it gets rendered it's a bunch of divs. I should also mention I'm using antd. When a user selects an option the onChange above is fired and I can see the text that was chosen.

Now based on the text I either want to make the background green or red.

So in the onchange do I use the old school document.getElementByClass to change the background. The selected item gets placed as text in an element that has a class name of "ant-select-selection-item". But since this is generated dynamically by antd I can't use useRef...

So how can I add and remove a class name from a div with the class name "ant-select-selection-item" ?

```
  const handleChange = (value: string, defaultOptionType: any) => {
    //??
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

can't you use the style prop of the option?  
And you can store the style in the state. Something like this.

https://codesandbox.io/s/select-with-search-field-antd-4-22-8-forked-yt1j6e?file=/demo.js:949-954

Comment: It somewhat works but the selected item as seen after it's selected needs to be either green or red depending on the text.  And that is in a div with class ""ant-select-selection-item" but this is generated at runtime. I can access it with document.getElementByClass but I don't think that is the proper way to do it... And I can't use useRef because the element doesn't exist

Comment: maybe I didn't understand something. Why can't you examine the value in the onChange method? 
In this case you can use the className prop and you just need to change the className property in the state when you want to change the color.
https://ant.design/components/select/

Comment: @szgezu
instead of sharing a codesandbox link, it will be great if you post same code here!so people dont need to open another page

Comment: poster has posted link in the post

Comment: What a huge problem

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood the question. But one solution could be to capture the option value and then filter over all the HTML select options to find the selected option and then add a class to it.

```
const handleChange = (value) => {
    // Get the selected option value
    const selectedValue = value.target.value || null;
    // Check taht there is a value
    if (selectedValue) {
      // Find the selected option element by the selected value
      const currentOption = [...value.target.options].filter((o) => o.value === selectedValue)
      // If there was a match add a class to the option
      if (currentOption.length > 0) {
        currentOption[0].classList.add("red");
      }
    }
  };
```